# Php 5.4.38 x64 is not seems to available

Tags: php

I am not able to get download php 5.4.38 64 bit.
Please help me from where i can get 64 bit php 5.4.38 because I am getting 32 bit php 5.4.38 everywhere.
If anyone having any link please share?

Thanks ....

Comment: `OS == Windows ? "No 64 bit version available" : ""`

Comment: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ if anywhere, but PHP 5.4 will be EOL within a couple of days

Answer (score 3):

Well, I wouldn't recommend to use PHP 5.4 anymore. Within 3 days it will hit it's end of life. thereby **no** more security updates.

I would recommend PHP 5.5 or higher.

[image: PHP EOL]

Answer (score 1):

The x64 builds of PHP for Windows is considered experimental, and do not yet provide 64-bit integer or large file support.